# Ubuntu 14.04 top taskbar missing

Tags: taskbar

My top taskbar is missing. No shutdown button, language indicator, date and time.
I have Ubuntu 14.04. See here what is missing.

[image: See here what is missing when I'm logged in with another user]

Comment: Very vague... Care to add more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Login to Ubuntu and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter TTY. Next, enter user name, password, and run the following command.

Code:

```
unity --reset
```

Wait until the process is complete and your user name appears again. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to renter the desktop environment.

If there is error reporting wait until finished. If Unity doesn't appear within a minute or two restart and login to Ubuntu and see what happens.

Try this for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To reset Unity, do

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: upvote this saved my day, just mention that the person has to restart cause most of the time it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get a hung taskbar relies on its daemon autostart if not already running, but works for sure in older versions such as Ubuntu 10.04
Could somebody test the method and post here whether it works on newer releases?

As above, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal

```
pgrep -u <username> gnome-panel
1234
kill 1234
```

Where you must replace `<username>` with yours and `1234` with the displayed pid of the `gnome-panel` program which had hung.

By comparison to the post above, killing a pid gets an instant (sub-second) result with no need to login again.