# No launcher or dash in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity

I have an Alienware Aurora Aurora R6 desktop computer with a NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti graphics card and pre-installed with Windows. I want to dual boot with Ubuntu, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and the NVIDIA driver. I am at the point where it will boot up in Ubuntu and I can login, but I just see the desktop background with no taskbar or icons or anything.

I first tried the solution given here ([Ubuntu 14.04 top taskbar missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511382/ubuntu-14-04-top-taskbar-missing)), but when I try `unity --reset`, it gives me errors like:

```
(process:2858): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

and it hangs.

Additionally, whenever I enter the console through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, it periodically gives me this error:

```
[601.02375] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: PCIe Bus Error: serverity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e2(Receiver ID)
[601.025902] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2:   device [8086:a292] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[601.027832] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2:    [ 0] Receiver Error
```

I have also tried the solution here (https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/), but it didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate but probably isn't of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults

Comment: I think your edit should be an answer, and you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity doesn't load - no Launcher or Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962497/ubuntu-16-04-unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-or-dash-appears)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the recommendation here ([Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity doesn't load - no Launcher or Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962497/ubuntu-16-04-unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-or-dash-appears)), created a new user, and it worked! But absolutely no idea why the first account didn't work. I just ended up deleting the first account.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo reboot
```

works for me!!!

Comment: You were suffering from a recent Kernel Update from Ubuntu LTS automatic updates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults